# Show the last version of a xml file in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a directory I have some files in the next format:
file_1_v1.xml
file_1_v2.xml
file_1_v3.xml
file_2_v1.xml
file_2_v1.xml
other_files.txt
other directories
I want to extract only the xml files with the highest version, in this case file_1_v3.xml and file_2_v1.xml.
I know the name of the files, in this case file_1 and file_2

Comment: Do all files have only two underscores?

Comment: No. They can have one or more underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
:nextName
   for %%a in ("%~1*.xml") do set "lastFile=%%a"
   echo Last version of %1 is %lastFile%
   shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto nextName
```

For example:

```
test.bat file_1 file_2
```

Comment: This solution works with these tests file, but in my real situation it doesn't work. I don't know how the files are iterated with this for, I wrote echo in case of set (after for...do) and the files are printed in a random order, not alphabetic.

Comment: It seems that for shows the files in the same order like dir does. I don't understand the order...it is neither by name, nor by size, nor by date...

Comment: I have modified your solution and it works now. Here it is:  `@echo off
setlocal
:nextName
   for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o:n "%~1_v?.xml"') do set "lastFile=%%~nxF"
   echo Last version of %1 is %lastFile%
   shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto nextName`